# `@discardableResult override init()` in Swift 3.1 throwing `warn_unused_result` Objective-C warning

Tags: objective-c, swift, objc-bridging-header

I have a Swift class that is bridged to Objective-C. Even with `@discardableResult`, it's throwing this warning on build in the Objective-C class:

> Ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute

Is there a way to silence this? This is in Xcode **8.3** with Swift **3.1**.

Comment: What is the point of the initializer if you're not using its result?

Comment: To initiate a singleton.

Comment: @BenGuild Singletons should be initialized automatically and the initializer should not be accessible. This seems like a correct warning caused by poor API architecture.

Answer (score 2):

A cast to `(void)` should silence the warning:

```
(void)[SingletonClass sharedInstance];
```

Comment: Thanks. The warning seems to have disappeared on its own.